# revert string direction (rtl/ltr) to string start

Tags: wpf, unicode, right-to-left

I have to join several user-entered fields for a header.

So let's say the user enters **A,B** in 2 fields, I will then display it as **A * B**.

The problem is when mixing English and Hebrew. If he enters **אA,5**, then I show **אA * 5**

Here it looks (logically) okay, but in a RTL label in `Wpf` it comes out something like this **A * 5א**.

I saw some posts about forcing direction with special `Unicode` charcters, but I dont know beforehand which language(s) the user will type into the data entry fields

What can be done?

With appreciation

Comment: You could possibly explicitly set flowdirection LeftToRight on your controls. Being English the whole idea of writing right to left is a bit strange. Foreign even :^) I don't know how that interacts with machine culture. None of the apps I've worked on are really truly localised even when they're internationally used.

Comment: Hi. The control's direction is correctly set to RTL, and hebrew chars work perfect. the problem is that ambiguous characters do not revert back to original rtl direction. all my apps are highly localized/multinational